# UML state machine diagram: triggered exit from a composite state

Tags: uml, diagram, transition, state-machine

I have an **UML state machine diagram**, which looks like this:

```
    +-----------------------------------+
    | A                                 |
    |      +------+  E1   +------+      |  E2   +-----+
o-->|  o-->|  A1  |------>|  A2  |------------->|  B  |
    |      +------+       +------+      |       +-----+
    |                                   |
    +-----------------+-----------------+
                      | E3
                      V
                   +-----+
                   |  C  |
                   +-----+
```

In reality, **composite state A** has so many sub-states that I'd like to extract it into a **separate diagram**. This means that the transition arrow from `A2` to `B` must be **cut in half by an exit point**.

**But where should I put event E2?** I think, I should put it on both sides of the exit point, that is, in both diagrams:

High-level diagram (the `o-o` is the decomposition icon, and `(X)` is the exit point):

```
    +-----------+
    |           |
    |           |   E2   +-----+
o-->|     A    (X)------>|  B  |
    |           |        +-----+
    |       o-o |
    +-----+-----+
          | E3
          V
       +-----+
       |  C  |
       +-----+
```

Low-level diagram:

```
+------------------------------------+
| A                                  |
|      +------+  E1   +------+  E2   |
|  o-->|  A1  |------>|  A2  |----->(X)
|      +------+       +------+       |
|                                    |
+------------------------------------+
```

Note that **`E2` is shown in both diagrams**. Unfortunately, I cannot find anything in the [UML spec](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/About-UML/) to support this idea. On the contrary, this approach apparently causes a conflict (see section 14.2.3.9.3). But I think there is no conflict here:

- Both transitions make the system leave state `A` and enter state `B`. So they practically form one transition.
- Both diagrams are easy to understand because both show `E2`, and the exit point looks like a "gate" between the two diagrams, through which the system's state "moves" from `(A, A2)` to `B`. I think it would be confusing to show `E2` only on one side of the exit point.
- If there were another similar transition, for example from `A1` to a state `D` (not shown), then it could be handled the same way, with a second exit point. However in that case the two exit points should be labeled differently (for example: "Exit from A1" and "Exit from A2").

**Is this valid UML?** If not, how should I solve this problem?

Comment: I recently was pointed towards https://www.omg.org/spec/PSSM/1.0/Beta1/ Gates, however, are no mentioned still (they only apply with interactions).

Comment: @ThomasKilian Thanks, I wasn't aware of this document. Skimming through it I found some examples, which put the event into the **low level** diagram only, that is, on the "inner side" of the exit point. When the event arrives, it triggers the transition **to** the exit point, and the second transition **from** the exit point is **automatic**, so there is no need to put the event on it. There is a similar argument in the UML spec, in the last paragraph of section 14.2.3.4.6.

Comment: @ThomasKilian Quote from this paragraph (emphasis mine): "Exit points are the inverse of entry points. That is, Transitions originating from a Vertex within the composite State can
terminate on the exit point. In a well-formed model, such a Transition should have a corresponding external Transition
outgoing from the same exit point, representing a **continuation** of the terminating Transition."

Comment: I also only skimmed that document. SMs are not my strong side and this document is 1.0 beta. No idea how UML and this doc will be handled by OMG in the future. Maybe they'll decouple SMs (partially) from UML since it's such a complex area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event should be placed on the internal party of the transition only.

Exit point is a pseudostate which essentially means it has no internal logic and as soon as the state machine reaches it, it "completes" meaning it is ready for the next transition. In your case you want the transition from `A2` to be triggered when `E2` occurs. That's why this event has to be placed on the internal part of a transition. On the other hand as soon as the transition reaches exit point (and it "completes") you want an uninterrupted further transition to `B` so no conditions should be placed on the outgoing (external) transition.

Placing `E2` on both "parts" of the transition will change the meaning of the diagram. It would stop transition on the exit pseudostate and wait until another `E2` event occurs. Only then (after **second** `E2` event) state machine will reach `B` state.

Placing `E2` on external part will also have a different meaning. The transition to exit point will occur only once the `A2` completes (even if `E2` occurs earlier) and only transition **from** exit point will wait for the `E2` event. On the other hand the transition to the exit point happens **as soon as** `A2` completes so if it happens any other possible transitions from `A2` (e.g. some `E4`) will no longer be available since the state machine has already **left** `A2` and waits on the exit point (for `E2`).

You've actually answered your own question in the comments but I hope my word of explanation justifies the full answer.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! This was also my understanding after reading the UML spec, more or less. What I don't like about it is that `E2` won't be shown on the high-level diagram, so looking at it wouldn't tell you what makes the system leave state `A`. The only way to show this is giving a meaningful label to the exit point, like "Exit A2 on E2".

Comment: Yes, a descriptive exit point name is a very good idea. Another option is to add a note attached to the exit point.

Answer (score 1):

What I'd do in that case is to show `A` with only `A2` inside and the rest left off. A note would tell "this is an excerpt of `A`".

```
    +----------------+
    | A (excerpt)    |
    |  +------+      |  E2   +-----+
o-->|  |  A2  |------------->|  B  |
    |  +------+      |       +-----+
    |                |
    +----------------+
```

Similarly you could leave out the `B` part by adding notes. Also (if the tool permits) you could add hyperlinks for detail diagrams where appropriate.

Comment: That's risky. Formally when a state is reached, all vertices (states and pseudostates) that has no incoming transitions are activated. So formally despite your note once the transition to A executes, A2 becomes an active state. If you want to follow this approach it would be safer to show the part leading to A2, but it'll cause an increasing complexity of the state internal logic and as a result (with multiple transitions like that) might be no longer serving the purpose.

Comment: @Ister It depends. If you have a complex SM and need ways to un-clutter it you must make compromises. Putting everything in one SM diagram which is not readable is also sort of risky. Diagrams are meant to transport the model's message. Then again I'm not that specialist for SMs...